# Stacked stone ledger panels exterior location

Tags: exterior

I am going to install stacked stone ledger panels on an exterior wall, which has 1/2 sheathing and a water-resistant barrier on it already.

I am planning on using cement board on top of the barrier and then applying the stacked stone using exterior-modified polymer thin-set. I'm fairly certain I cannot put the thin-set on a barrier.

Is this a suitable way to proceed or am I likely to run into issues?

Comment: Got any more detail on this "stacked stone?"  Is it really stacked stone, or is it really just a veneer?  If so, what does the manufacturer say about installation?

Comment: Is this wall under a roof or is it subject to rain?  If the sheathing has a water resistant barrier, why add cement board?  A pic or 2 and a better explanation of your project would get better results.

Comment: We really don't do "thoughts".  We answer precise questions.